# Woocommerce: use gallery image as product image at Shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm trying to use the first (will be *the only*, in fact) gallery image of a product as the product's image to display on the Shop page. I've tried messing around with the `WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()` hook at archive-product.php but arrived at nothing after several hours, and cannot find any answer to this topic.

I'm working on the last version of Storefront theme and the last version of Woocommerce and Wordpress, in case that information could be useful.

Wordpress: 4.9.6
Woocommerce: 3.3.5
Storefront: 2.3.1

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please list the version numbers for future reference.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your advice, i'll edit.

Comment: Still waiting for solution :(